# Динамическое определение RadioButton C# WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, form

уважаемые пользователя StackOverFLow.
Возникла проблема с тем, чтобы считать состояние Checked у динамически созданных radiobutton. Вообще суть такая: по нажатию кнопки создаются radiobutton указанное количество штук, далее требуется по нажатию другой кнопки считать в переменную, какая из этих radiobutton была выбрана.
Код создания radiobutton:

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "One right answer")
        {
            switch (comboBox2.Text)
            {
                case "1":
                    {
                        count = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                case "2":
                    {
                        count = 2;
                        break;
                    }
                case "3":
                    {
                        count = 3;
                        break;
                    }
                case "4":
                    {
                        count = 4;
                        break;
                    }
                case "5":
                    {
                        count = 5;
                        break;
                    }
                case "6":
                    {
                        count = 6;
                        break;
                    }
                case "7":
                    {
                        count = 7;
                        break;
                    }
                case "8":
                    {
                        count = 8;
                        break;
                    }
                case "9":
                    {
                        count = 9;
                        break;
                    }
                case "10":
                    {
                        count = 10;
                        break;
                    }
            }

            RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[count];
            for (count = 0; count < tb.Length; count++)
            {
                rb[count] = new RadioButton
                {
                    Width = 20,
                    Visible = true,
                    Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 14 + count * 30)
                };
                panel1.Controls.Add(rb[count]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: А что мешает просто сделать что то на подобии `count = int.Parse(comboBox2.Text)`? Зачем этот велосипед? Что будете делать, если у вас может быть 1000 значений?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: там стоит ограничение до 10. Но я вот не понял немного с вашей строкой: как именно она мне должна помочь с определением выбранной radiobutton?

Comment: Сделайте массив `RadioButton[] rb` _полем_ формы. При нажатии на кнопку проходите по этому массиву и проверяете свойство `Checked`.

Comment: Я вам не говорю про решение задачи. Просто говорю, что весь ваш switch можно заменить одной строкой. Учитесь с самого начала писать компактно и понятно.

Comment: @Evgeniy: понял, тогда спасибо за совет

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать. Мне выдает, что инициализатор поля не может обращаться к нестатическому полю.